# Equivalence of different definitions of sup in expectations

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, statistics

So the context of my question comes from the proof of Theorem 7.3.1(Norms of Gaussian random matrices) from High Dimensional Probability by Vershynin.

In particular assume $A$ is an $m$ by $n$ matrices with independent $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ entries. Define $T=\mathbb{S}^{n-1}\times \mathbb{S}^{m-1}$. Let $X_{uv}=\langle Au,  v\rangle$ where $u\in\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ and $v\in \mathbb{S}^{m-1}$.

We know that the operator norm of $A$ is equivalently defined as $||A|| = \sup_{(u,v)\in T} X_{uv}$. Now the book claims the following equivalence.

$$E||A|| = \sup_{S\subset T} E \left(\sup_{(u,v)\in S} X_{uv}\right)$$

where the outer $sup$ is over all finite subsets $S$ of $T$. I do not see why this is true at all. Could someone please explain?

More generally, my concern is when it is true for a random process $X_t$ that

$$E \sup_{t\in T} X_t= \sup_{S\subset T} E\left( \sup_{t\in S} X_t\right)$$

where again the outer $sup$ is over finite subsets $S$ of $T$. I ask this because this is how Vershynin defines these expectations in the book by taking the sup over finite subsets to avoid measurability issues. I was wondering what merits these definitions because it seems to be commonplace in a lot of introductory high dimensional statistics/probability books.

Comment: Where exactly do you see that equivalence? In the proof of Theorem 7.3.1?

Comment: It's used when he tries to invoke Sudakov-Fernique inequality towards the end of the proof when he writes $E||A||=E\sup_{(u,v)\in T} X_{uv} \leq E\sup_{(u,v)\in T}Y_{uv}$. At the beginning of the chapter he mentions in one of the footnotes that the sup is defined to be sup over finite subsets, so his version of Sudakov-Fernique inequality applies to suprmum over finite subsets definition, which would imply that the above equality on the left hand side is what I have written in my original post.

Comment: The author, actually, argues that since $\sup_t X_t$ need not be measurable, he interprets $\mathsf{E}\sup_t X_t$ as the supremum of $\mathsf{E}\sup_{t\in T_0} X_t$ over all finite subset $T_0$.

Comment: Right that's what the author says, but what justifies the equality $E||A||=\sup_{S\subset T} E\left ( \sup_{(u,v)\in S} X_{uv}\right )=E\sup_{(u,v)\in T} X_{uv}$ in the proof of theorem 7.3.1?

Comment: You can get proper norm bars by using `\|` instead of two vertical bars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, this is not true. Let $U$ be a uniformly distributed random variable on $T:=[0,1]$. Define,

$$X_t = \begin{cases} 0 &\text{ if } t \neq U\\ 1 &\text{ if } t = U\end{cases}.$$

Then for any finite $S\subset T$, $\mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{t\in S}X_t\right] = 0$, so,

$$\sup_{S\subset T} \mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{t \in S} X_t\right] = 0 \neq 1 = \mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{t \in T} X_t\right].$$

Splitting the supremum works in the proof you mentioned because $(u,v)\mapsto X_{(u,v)}$ is continuous in $T:=\mathbb{S}^{n-1}\times\mathbb{S}^{m-1}$.

Let $\tilde{S} \subset T$ be a countable dense subset of $T$. Then by continuity of $(u,v) \mapsto X_{(u,v)}$,

$$\sup_{(u,v) \in \tilde{S}} X_{(u,v)} = \sup_{(u,v) \in T} X_{(u,v)} \text{ almost surely}.$$

Let $S_1 \subset S_2 \subset \cdots$ be a sequence of finite sets growing to $\tilde{S}$, and suppose $(0,0) \in S_1$. Then for all $n$,

$$\sup_{(u,v) \in S_n} X_{(u,v)} \geq X_{(0,0)} = \langle A0,0\rangle = 0\text{ almost surely,}$$

so the quantity $\sup_{(u,v) \in S_n} X_{(u,v)}$ is non-negative and almost surely non-decreasing. Applying monotone convergence,

$$\sup_{S \subset T} \mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{(u,v) \in S} X_{(u,v)}\right] \geq \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{(u,v)\in S_n}X_{(u,v)}\right] = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{(u,v)\in S_n}X_{(u,v)}\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{(u,v) \in \tilde{S}} X_{(u,v)}\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{(u,v) \in T} X_{(u,v)}\right].$$

The other direction of the inequality is trivial. For any finite $S$,

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{(u,v)\in S} X_{(u,v)}\right] \leq \mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{(u,v) \in T} X_{(u,v)}\right].$$

Taking a supremum,

$$\sup_{S \subset T}\mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{(u,v)\in S} X_{(u,v)}\right] \leq \mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{(u,v) \in T} X_{(u,v)}\right].$$

We can then conclude,

$$\sup_{S \subset T}\mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{(u,v)\in S} X_{(u,v)}\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{(u,v) \in T} X_{(u,v)}\right].$$

Edit: I just realized I made a pretty big mistake. I'll leave the original up anyway. The problem is that $(0,0) \notin \mathbb{S}^{n-1}\times \mathbb{S}^{m-1}$. However, notice that for any (not necessarily finite) $S \subseteq T$,

$$\left|\sup_{(u,v) \in S} X_{(u,v)}\right| \leq \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n|A_{ij}|,$$

which is integrable. Therefore we can switch the limit and the expectation using the Dominated Convergence Theorem instead of the Monotone Convergence Theorem.

Comment: If you're curious about how general this answer is, I haven't thought much about it, but a few things come to mind. First, you want to choose an appropriate function space on which to define $t\mapsto X_t$ so that $\sup_{t\in T}X_t$ can be determined by a countable number of deterministically chosen points. I chose to work in the space of continuous functions. Second, you need some uniform integrability or monotonicity that allows you to interchange the expectation and limit. Luckily the context you provided in your question has a very natural non-negative monotone structure, so I used MCT.

Comment: Thanks forgottenarrow.